# UWP How Packaging APP if I use SqLite

Tags: sqlite, package, uwp

I use SQLite in my UWP App.
All work good on my PC in debug mode.

After installation on a W10 Device the APP close itselfs when I try to create a SQLite's Database.

I think it's a write-problem on the device.
Perhaps no write rights?

Where and How can I set it on my package?

Thanks a lot
Daniele Pinai

Comment: I had insert a messageDialog to read the error message.
'Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3'  so i think i must to put this dll in the package ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click your **UWP project** in the **Solution Explorer** and choose `Add -> Reference...`.

In the dialog window choose **Universal Windows** and below select **Extensions**.

In this list ensure that `Visual C++ 2015 Runtime for Universal Windows` and `SQLite for Universal Windows Platform` are checked.

In case you can't find the `SQLite for Universal Windows Platform` there, you will have to install this extension. You can do this using the **Extensions and Updates** window in Visual Studio, or by downloading and installing the latest `sqlite-uwp-` package from the [SQLite website](http://sqlite.org/download.html).

Comment: Yes ...my problem was  the reference  ' Visual C++ 2015 Runtime for Universal Windows '  that i have forgot.  Thanks